# Error in using GUIDE in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

This is the code for my GUI using GUIDE

```
function varargout = testcreat(varargin)
    gui_Singleton = 1;
    gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                       'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                       'gui_OpeningFcn', @testcreat_OpeningFcn, ...
                       'gui_OutputFcn',  @testcreat_OutputFcn, ...
                       'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                       'gui_Callback',   []);
    if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
        gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
    end

    if nargout
        [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    else
        gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    end

function testcreat_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
    handles.output = hObject;
    guidata(hObject, handles);

function varargout = testcreat_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
    varargout{1} = handles.output;

function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

function edit1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
        set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
    end

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    a=get(handles.edit1,'String');
    set(handles.text1,'String',a);
    guidata(hObject,handles);
```

I am trying to build a GUI in Matlab and the above code is a test. However it doesn't run, and it gives error information like:

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
Error in testcreat>pushbutton1_Callback (line 104)
    a=get(handles.edit1,'String');
Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});
Error in testcreat (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
Error in @(hObject,eventdata)testcreat('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Do anybody know why is it?

Comment: It looks ok to me. Are you sure that the `edit1` textfield still exists in GUIDE and is called like that? When clicking save in GUIDE, the .m file is updated, this sometimes helps.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure the textfield exists and the tags have no problem. And I do have saved .m file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. ORZ
It is because i tried to use the GUI by directly operating in the `.fig` file. If so the data cannot transmit.
And the correct way is to push the run button in the `.m` file!

Hope nobody will do the same stupid thing like what i did.